# Iterate PSObject hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, psobject

One of the properties (`identity`) in my PSObject object is a hashtable like this which is returned from PowerShell:

```
@{name=something; Number=87354}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach (PSObject ticket in tickets)
{
      var a = ticket.Properties["identity"].Value;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.name); //error
}
```

How can I access the properties inside of the hashtable?

Comment: `((IDictionary)(a is PSObject ? ((PSObject)a).BaseObject : a))["name"]`

Comment: @PetSerAl Throws me this error: using the generic type requires 2 arguments

Comment: `using System.Collections`

Comment: @PetSerAl Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionary'.

Comment: Are you sure that your `identity` property is `Hashtable` and not something else? And which PowerShell version you are targeting?